# DXF viewer in android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am now able to read the DXF file but I am struck at drawing the image on the Android UI.

I have checked the DXF file format [here](http://www.autodesk.com/techpubs/autocad/acad2000/dxf/index.htm).

I know that I have to use the OpenGL API to draw it. But confused as to where to start drawing it while reading the DXF file.

Can some one point me to a link(s) or let me know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to answer such a general question... Here's a catch-all responseL

OpenGL ES is limited in how it can draw data.
You are restricted to drawing points, lines, triangles, triangle strips, and triangle fans. It cannot draw Quads or NGons.
Assuming your DXF files have to support NGons, you have a few options:

1. make assumptions about the NGon faces (like they aren't too concave), calculate a center for the face and use that to draw each face as a triangle_fan
2. build your own ngon subdivision methods and display as triangles
3. display only the wireframes
4. combine ((1 | 2) & 3)

As for actually using openGL to draw, I'd recommend the great tutorials in the Android Development Reference:

[OpenGL ES 1.0](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es10.html)

[OpenGL ES 2.0](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es20.html)

Using the GL ES 2.0 example, you would modify the initShapes() method to load your DXF data into the bytebuffer (check out the documentation [here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml)). Then you'd modify the onDrawFrame method in your Renderer class to use the byteBuffer with the proper parameters and draw the arrays in the preferred method (GL_LINES or GL_LINE_STRIP for wireframe as one example).

Hopefully that helps